# Warning on "diff.renamelimit variable" when doing git push

Tags: git, warnings, push

I'm pushing the local commit to the remote git server and got the following warning messages:

```
remote: warning: only found copies from modified paths due to too many files.
remote: warning: you may want to set your diff.renamelimit variable to at least 19824 and retry the command.
```

But actually I've already set the diff.renamelimit to 0 (I think zero means unlimited, right?).

```
$ git config --list
...
diff.renamelimit=0
```

So what shall I do to avoid this warning? Thanks.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-config) doesn't mention 0 as a special value for `diff.renamelimit`.
So you should set that limit to the value recommended.
Or you can try deactivating the rename detection altogether. (`git config diff.renames 0`)

You will find a similar example in this blog post "[Confluence, git, rename, merge oh my...](https://atlassianblog.wpengine.com/archives/confluence_git_rename_merge_oh_my)":

> As already mentioned, git tries to detect file renames after that fact, for example when using `git log` or `git diff/merge`.
> When trying to detect renames git distinguishes between exact and inexact renames with the former being a rename without changing the content of the file and the latter a rename that might include changes to the content of the file (e.g. renaming/moving a Java Class).
> This distinction is important because the algorithm for detecting exact renames is linear and will always be executed while the algorithm for inexact rename detection is quadratic ( `O(n^2)` ) and git does not attempt to do this if the number of files changed exceeds a certain threshold (1000 by default).

> As the number of files affected by the recent reorganisation exceeds this threshold, git simply gives up and leaves the merge resolution up to the developer. In our case we can avoid doing manual merge resolution though by changing the threshold

---

Note: Git 2.16 (Q1 2018) will amend that limit:

Historically, the diff machinery for rename detection had a
hardcoded limit of 32k paths; this is being lifted to allow users
trade cycles with a (possibly) easier to read result.

See [commit 8997355](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89973554b52cb533b01acfdcb16d8215344bf004) (29 Nov 2017) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
See [commit 9268cf4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9268cf4a2ef61c334204b1237b2174a77d16f98d), [commit 9f7e4bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f7e4bfa3b6da16e3690312ff208cc27706b2c1b), [commit d6861d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6861d0258df95987696eab6c9bbc138a07190b9), [commit b520abf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b520abf1c8f3dcbd218c9ae26830b7e2c94866c7) (13 Nov 2017) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6466854](https://github.com/git/git/commit/646685460c26d56b149da91544e76150119d9c9b), 19 Dec 2017)</sup>

> ### `diff`: remove silent clamp of `renameLimit`

> In [commit 0024a54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0024a54923a12f8c05ce4290f5ebefab0cce4336) (Fix the rename detection limit checking; Sept. 2007, Git v1.5.3.2), the `renameLimit` was clamped to 32767.
> This appears to have been to simply avoid integer overflow in the following computation:
>
> ```
> num_create * num_src <= rename_limit * rename_limit
> ```
>
> Although it also could be viewed as a hard-coded bound on the amount of CPU
> time we're willing to allow users to tell git to spend on handling
> renames.
> An upper bound may make sense, but unfortunately this upper
> bound was neither communicated to the users, nor documented anywhere.
>
> Although large limits can make things slow, we have users who would be
> ecstatic to have a small five file change be correctly cherry picked even if they have to manually specify a large limit and wait ten minutes for the renames to be detected.
>
> Existing scripts and tools that use "`-l0`" to continue working, treating 0 as a special value indicating that the rename limit is to be a very large number.

---

Git 2.17 (Q2 2018) will avoid showing a warning message in the middle of a line of "`git diff`" output.

See [commit 4e056c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e056c989f8642050973ba1aabc687979f41798c) (16 Jan 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 17c8e0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17c8e0b33dc6d0fc975fb4ca1d78d859e77791a6), 13 Feb 2018)</sup>

> ### `diff.c`: flush `stdout` before printing rename warnings

> The diff output is buffered in a `FILE` object and could still be
> partially buffered when we print these warnings (directly to `fd 2`).
> The output is messed up like this
>
> ```
> worktree.c                                   |   138 +-
> worktree.h        warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
>                                              |    12 +-
> wrapper.c                                    |    83 +-
> ```
>
> It gets worse if the warning is printed after color codes for the graph part are already printed. You'll get a warning in green or red.
>
> Flush stdout first, so we can get something like this instead:
>
> ```
> xdiff/xutils.c                               |    42 +-
> xdiff/xutils.h                               |     4 +-
> 1033 files changed, 150824 insertions(+), 69395 deletions(-)
> warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
> ```

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), documentation on "[`git diff -l<n>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/268055bfdec5cc2228ade6f3ff7094632568c82a/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> and `diff.renameLimit` have been updated, and the defaults for these limits have been raised.

See [commit 94b82d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94b82d56866793018a7a9bcbe20c1c061fa41aa8), [commit 9dd29db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dd29dbef01e39fe9df81ad9e5e193128d8c5ad5), [commit 6623a52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6623a528e00b73f5438724a355c43343d3de8652), [commit 05d2c61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05d2c61c6744212cdef6085832a84b49da77591c) (15 Jul 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 268055b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/268055bfdec5cc2228ade6f3ff7094632568c82a), 28 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`diffcore-rename`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dd29dbef01e39fe9df81ad9e5e193128d8c5ad5): treat a `rename_limit` of 0 as unlimited
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> In [commit 8997355](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89973554b52cb533b01acfdcb16d8215344bf004) ("`diffcore-rename`: make diff-tree -l0 mean -l", 2017-11-29, Git v2.16.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/646685460c26d56b149da91544e76150119d9c9b) listed in [batch #10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/936d1b989416a95f593bf81ccae8ac62cd83f279)), `-l0` was given a special magical "large" value, but one which was not large enough for some uses (as can be seen from [commit 9f7e4bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f7e4bfa3b6da16e3690312ff208cc27706b2c1b) ("`diff`: remove silent clamp of `renameLimit`", 2017-11-13, Git v2.16.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/646685460c26d56b149da91544e76150119d9c9b) listed in [batch #10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/936d1b989416a95f593bf81ccae8ac62cd83f279)).
> Make 0 (or a negative value) be treated as unlimited instead and update the documentation to mention this.

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9dd29dbef01e39fe9df81ad9e5e193128d8c5ad5/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L601):

> Note that a value of 0 is treated as unlimited.

Answer (score 114):

```
git config merge.renameLimit 999999
```

What does **merge.renameLimit** mean

> The number of files to consider when performing rename detection during a merge; if not specified, defaults to the value of **diff.renameLimit**.

source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: why is this `merge.renameLimit` instead of `diff.renameLimit`?

Comment: @pgpb.padilla very similar

Comment: git config diff.renameLimit 999999 (insert your own number) worked for me.

Comment: Is there a reason why someone might _not_ want to max this out? Why does the limit exist in the first place? Just to save your CPU from insanely large merges?

Comment: @pgpb.padilla, my warning said: **warning: you may want to set your `merge.renamelimit` variable to at least 1659 and retry the command.** So, `git config merge.renamelimit 10000` seems to be the right command for me (I'm setting the limit to 10000 here). Once you've set it, you can read back your setting with `git config merge.renamelimit`.

Comment: @pgpb.padilla, I'm guessing on older versions of `git`, the variable used to be named `diff.renameLimit` instead of `merge.renameLimit`, which it is now.

Comment: Both `diff.renameLimit` and `merge.renameLimit` are settings you can tweak. 
Section in [git-book](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-config#Documentation/merge-config.txt-mergerenameLimit) says that `merge.renameLimit` is "The number of files to consider when performing rename detection during a merge; if not specified, defaults to the value of `diff.renameLimit`."

Answer (score 5):

In case you aren't constantly running into this problem, but instead it's just a one-off thing then changing the global config from it's default value might be an overkill. I would suggest you simply use the `-c` option to set a special config just for this one command. Something like:

```
git -c "diff.renamelimit=19824" push
```