# Can't commit updated jar file

Tags: git, android-studio, jar

I created a some_library_v1.jar and created an testApp to show how to use this jar and finally pushed the testApp on our server.

Then requirements were changed and I updated jar, replaced it with new name some_library_v2.jar and pushed the testApp again.
But it turned out that Android Studio thinks that I only changed name of jar.
As a workaround I just added old jar and pushed it again, so, now folder libs contains several versions of my library.

My question is how to make Android Studio understand that I have changed a library but not only jar's name?

Comment: Binary files and VCS don't really get along well. If you have alternatives, you should avoid committing and pushing these. Some times you don't have a choice, but don't expect accurate result on diffing. Also, you should add a tag with whatever VCS you're using.

Comment: @Zoe, I use Git

Comment: Yeah, generally speaking build artifacts (and other generated content) shouldn't be committed. Is there a specific reason you're doing this?

Comment: @Chris, I have to save a project with my jar on the server because another developer(s) have to have a real example of using that. Maybe I have to store that jar in some other folder? I mean, that I can write a comment in a code that last version of the jar exists in "some_folder" and he has to move it to libs folder and delete old jar from libs.

Comment: @LumisD, what does your server have to do with anything? Git isn't a deployment tool, it's a version control tool. If you're committing a `.jar` just so you can copy it somewhere your workflow is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Without discussing the best practice (ie, regenerate a jar from sources compilation), try instead:

```
git rm -- old.jar
git commit -m "Remove jar v1"

git add -- new.jar
git commit -m "Add jar V2"
```

That should be enough to record those events properly (and [not as a "rename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27018980/6309)")