# vite react docker production build not working

Tags: reactjs, docker, vite

I'm trying to get my vite react app into production via docker. I'm stuck getting it to build correctly. Everything works locally.

Error message:

```
vite v4.3.5 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 85 modules transformed.
✓ built in 1.73s
[vite:load-fallback] Could not load /app/src/components/layouts/DefaultLayout (imported by src/routes/accounts/Accounts.jsx): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/src/components/layouts/DefaultLayout'
error during build:
Error: Could not load /app/src/components/layouts/DefaultLayout (imported by src/routes/accounts/Accounts.jsx): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/src/components/layouts/DefaultLayout'
Service 'frontend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Top of App.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import DefaultLayout from "@/components/layouts/DefaultLayout";
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS build
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 g++ make
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm install -g vite
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM ubuntu As prod
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
COPY --from=build /app/dist /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 90 
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import dns from "dns";
import * as path from "path";

dns.setDefaultResultOrder("verbatim");

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: "dist",
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: "@", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src") }],
  },
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    host: true,
    strictPort: true,
    port: 90,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue on Stack Overflow that seems similar to what you're facing: [git fails to detect renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805750/git-fails-to-detect-renaming)

It could be causing your problem if your file and folder names have the same spelling but differ in case sensitivity. Check if the filenames are correct in both your Git repository and your local setup. That might be the key to fixing your issue.

Faced exact same issue and making sure file and folder name case sensitivity
on local and in git repo resolved my issue.

Hope this helps!